# Bring newly inserted record in the top in MYSQL when record with the same value are present in the table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table(name of table is `symbols`) with two columns `symbol` and `weight`. I want to sort this table in descending order according to the weight. I had done this by using

```
ALTER TABLE symbols ORDER BY weight DESC
```

Above statement gives me given below output.

```
x5  0.40
x3  0.20
x4  0.20
x1  0.10
x2  0.10
```

but I have one more to constrain to apply in this sorting. 
Suppose I am adding one more record with in the table ('x22',0.10). After inserting and sorting with the help of(`ALTER TABLE symbols ORDER BY weight DESC`) , my table looks like

```
x5  0.40
x3  0.20
x4  0.20
x1  0.10
x2  0.10
**x22   0.10**
```

but i want to get the result like this

```
x5  0.40
x3  0.20
x4  0.20
**x22   0.10**
x1  0.10
x2  0.10
```

I want to get the newly inserted record to be in the top, if table contains records with same weight.

Through some searching on google I came to know that My DB design is bad and should have added one more column for time-stamp. But, I am already having data in table can I handle this with query, without changing the table structure? 
Thank you in Advance.

Comment: you have to add datetime column in your table then you can get desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I remind you of

> [ORDER BY enables you to create the new table with the rows in a
>   specific order. ***Note that the table does not remain in this order
>   after inserts and deletes.***
>
>   ...
>
>   ORDER BY does not make sense for InnoDB tables that contain a
>   user-defined clustered index (PRIMARY KEY or NOT NULL UNIQUE index).
>   InnoDB always orders table rows according to such an index if one is
>   present.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

You can simply add another column

```
ALTER TABLE symbols ADD COLUMN created_or_modified timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Then query your table simply with

```
SELECT * FROM symbols ORDER BY created_or_modified DESC;
```

Or an auto_increment column would also be possible.

P.S.: To quote the manual further:

> By using this option after major changes to the table, you *might* be able to get higher performance. In some cases, it *might* make sorting easier for MySQL if the table is in order by the column that you want to order it by later.

Please note the extensive use of the word "might"!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE symbols ORDER BY symbol DESC, weight DESC
```

**UPDATE:** if you had an `id` column that had a `AUTO_INCREMENT` you could use this:

```
ALTER TABLE symbols ORDER BY weight DESC, id DESC
```

Comment: This is a Good idea, but symbol will not be in order every-time. In this example they are in Order. For Example if newly inserted record is (x0,.10) then you suggestion wont work. :( . Can you think of something else please.

Comment: @MohdSuleman i see ur point now... but for that you would need and extra auto_increment column in order to detect the newly inserted row